# get lowest price using php

Tags: php, sql

```
Product |  bprice  |    fprice
abcd    |  89      |    65
ebcd    |  39      |    105
fbcd    |  23      |    45
gbcd    |  89      |    
hbcd    |  89      |    65
ibcd    |          |    65
jbcd    |  50      |    50
```

sql+php

how to  get low price  of each product using php script after fetching mysql records like

for abcd $price = 65
  for fbed $price = 23
  for gbcd  $price = 89
  etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM product group by product";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
   if($row->bprice > $row->fprice)
   {
       $low=$row->fprice;
   } 
    else
   {
   $low=$row->bprice;
    }
}
```

Comment: if($item['price'] == '(null)' or $item['price'] == '')
   $price = $item['fc_price'];
  else if($item['fc_price'] == '(null)' or $item['fc_price'] == '')
   $price = $item['price'];
  else
   $price  = min($item['price'],$item['fc_price']); 
  echo $price;
I have done myself

Comment: @Tahseen  You're allowed to answer your own question.  You should post that as a properly formatted answer.  I'd vote it up.

Answer (score 5):

`min($bprice,$fprice)` should do what you need.

---

Edit: Fix to handle null

```
if (is_null($bprice)) {
    $price = $fprice;
} elseif (is_null($fprice)) {
    $price = $bprice;
} else {
    $price = min($bprice,$fprice);
}
```

Comment: If you wish to do this in MySQL for some reason, you can fetch it like this: `LEAST(bprice, fprice) AS lowest_price`

Comment: gbcd    |  89      |    (null)
not working on this condition , give (null)

Comment: Ah, I see.  Okay, we can work around that.  I'll edit the answer to fix that problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use the group by statement:

```
SELECT MAX(bprice) AS maxbprice, MAX(fprice) AS maxfprice
FROM products
GROUP BY Product
```

Comment: he specifically asked IN PHP, so not in sql.

Comment: In the question he mentions 'sql+php', so I'm guessing not specifically?

Comment: "how to  get low price of each product using php script after fetching mysql records like" Pretty clear if you ask me.

Comment: @dragon112: if MySQL single can do this, and retrieve the same result whatever user required, then why should use PHP?

Comment: @Chandresh I agree with you, im just mentioning that it is not what the question described. Maybe he wants to save some load on the MySQL server?

Comment: I don't understand this answer.  He wanted the lower price of the two prices for each item.  This just gives back the price for each product.  How does this answer whether the bprice or fprice is lower?  Also, why do group by product when there's only on product in each row?